# Verilog counter always block is not working

Tags: verilog

I have trouble with the `PC` part of the following code. It should count from 0 and on, but it does not count when I run the testbench file. I talked with TA and could not figure out why the testbench file is not counting up the PC register. When I run the testbench file, `PC` spits out some garbage value somehow. Can anyone help me out to figure out why it is not working?

```
#                    0TEST MY DESIGN
#                    0Address bus:          x, STR Data :          x, LDR Data :          x, Read: x, Write: x, PC:          x, Reset is x
#                    2Address bus:          x, STR Data :          x, LDR Data :          x, Read: 0, Write: 0, PC:          x, Reset is 0
#                    6Address bus:          x, STR Data :          x, LDR Data :          x, Read: 0, Write: 0, PC:          x, Reset is 1
#                   11Address bus:         10, STR Data :          x, LDR Data :          7, Read: 1, Write: 0, PC:          x, Reset is 1
#                   21Address bus:          7, STR Data :          2, LDR Data :          7, Read: 0, Write: 1, PC:          x, Reset is 1
#                   31Address bus:         10, STR Data :          2, LDR Data :          9, Read: 1, Write: 0, PC:          x, Reset is 1
#                   41Address bus:          9, STR Data :          7, LDR Data :          9, Read: 0, Write: 1, PC:          x, Reset is 1
#                   51Address bus:          x, STR Data :          7, LDR Data :          9, Read: 0, Write: 0, PC:          x, Reset is 1
```

Code:

```
module MemoryControl
(
Clk,PC,Reset,Result,source1,source2,opcode,LDR_EN,Address_EN,AddBus,DataBus_L,DataBus_S,LDRin,R,W
);

/*Variable*/
input [31:0] Result,source1,source2,DataBus_L;
input [3:0] opcode;
input Clk,Reset;
output reg LDR_EN, Address_EN;
output reg [31:0]PC,LDRin,AddBus,DataBus_S;
output reg R,W;

/*PC Count Always Block. PC counts from 0 to 16*/
always@(posedge Clk)
begin
if (!Reset)
PC = 0;
else PC = PC + 1;
end

/*LDR MUX Always Block opcode 4'b1110*/
always@*
begin
if (opcode == 4'b1110)
begin
LDR_EN = 1;
Address_EN = 1;
R = 1; W = 0;
    /*Address Mux LDR data fetch*/
    case (Address_EN)  
    0: AddBus = PC;
    1: AddBus = source1;
    default: AddBus = 0; 
    endcase
    /*Fetched LDR data outputs to register bank*/
    case (LDR_EN)  
    1: LDRin = DataBus_L;
    0: LDRin = Result;
    default: LDRin = 0;
    endcase 
end
end

/*STR MUX Always Block opcode 1101*/
always@*
begin
if (opcode == 4'b1101)
begin
Address_EN = 1;
DataBus_S = source2;
W = 1; R = 0; 
    case (Address_EN)  
    0: AddBus = PC;
    1: AddBus = source1;
    default: AddBus = 0;
    endcase
end
end

/*Fetch Instruction from PC when not STR or LDR*/
always@*
begin
if (opcode == !4'b1110 && opcode == !4'b1101)
begin
Address_EN = 0;
R = 0; W = 0;
    case (Address_EN) 
    0: AddBus = PC;
    1: AddBus = source1;
    default: AddBus = 0; 
    endcase
end
end
endmodule
```

And the following module is a testbench file of the above Verilog file.

```
module MemoryContro_t;

reg [31:0] Result_t,source1_t,source2_t,DataBus_L_t;
reg [3:0] opcode_t;
reg Clk_t,Reset_t;
wire LDR_EN_t, Address_EN_t;
wire [31:0]PC_t, AddBus_t,DataBus_S_t,LDRin_t;
wire R_t,W_t;

initial begin
$display($time,"TEST MY DESIGN");
#2 Result_t=0; source1_t=0; source2_t=0; DataBus_L_t = 0; opcode_t=0; Reset_t = 0; 
#4 Reset_t = 1;
#5 Result_t=0; source1_t=10; source2_t=5; DataBus_L_t = 7; opcode_t=4'b1110;  // LDR Test ,LDR Data initialized
#10 Result_t=0; source1_t=7; source2_t=2; DataBus_L_t = 6; opcode_t=4'b1101;  // STR Test ,STR Data initialized 
#10 Result_t=0; source1_t=10; source2_t=5; DataBus_L_t = 9; opcode_t=4'b1110; // LDR Test ,LDR Data overwritten
#10 Result_t=0; source1_t=9; source2_t=7; DataBus_L_t = 10; opcode_t=4'b1101; // STR Test ,STR Data overwritten
#10 Result_t=0; source1_t=9; source2_t=7; DataBus_L_t = 10; opcode_t=!4'b1101&&4'b1110; // PC TEST

end

always #5 Clk_t=~Clk_t;
initial begin
$monitor($time,"Address bus: %d, STR Data : %d, LDR Data : %d, Read: %d, Write: %d, PC: %d, Reset is %d", AddBus_t, DataBus_S_t,LDRin_t,R_t,W_t,PC_t, Reset_t);
end

MemoryControl MUT (.Clk(Clk_t),.PC(PC_t),.Reset(Reset_t),.Result(Result_t),.source1(source1_t),.source2(source2_t),.opcode(opcode_t),
.LDR_EN(LDR_EN_t),.Address_EN(Address_EN_t),.AddBus(AddBus_t),.DataBus_L(DataBus_L_t),.DataBus_S(DataBus_S_t),.LDRin(LDRin_t),.R(R_t),.W(W_t));
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your clock signal in your testbench module.  You declared it as `reg`, which means its initial value is X (unknown).

```
initial Clk_t = 0;
```

It remains X throughout your simulation, which means that the `PC` value will never increment because `always@(posedge Clk)` is not triggered.

If you are not debugging your simulations using waveforms, you should.  I noticed the problem immediately when I looked at waves.

Answer (score -1):

1. The clock has not a initial value, you can set it with following style:
   reg Clk_t = 1'b0 ;
2. The reset in you DUT is active low, so in TB you should set the Result_t to 0 and then set it to 1.

Comment: Your 2nd point is incorrect.  Run the simulation and look at waveforms. The reset signal is 0 at time 2, then it is set to 1 at time 6, and it remains 1 as it should for the entire simulation.  The `Result_t` signal is not the reset signal (`Reset_t`).